# how to except timoutexception in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
# im testing each exception by putting time.sleep and test each exceptions.
a = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="gLFyf gsfi"]')))
try:
    print(a.text)
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException) as e:
    print('fail')
```

i want to detect if the selenium throw out some errors so it does not crash immediately. both Nosuchelement and staleelement work perfectly as expected and print out fail. However, timoutexception from webdriverwait never go inside except to print out fail but it crash the script how come? my question is am i not suppose to mix timoutexception with webdriverwait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to rearrange your code so the `timeoutException` is actually thrown inside the `try` block. It could look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
# im testing each exception by putting time.sleep and test each exceptions.

try:
    a = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="gLFyf gsfi"]')))
    print(a.text)
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException) as e:
    print('fail')
```